# Remove a fastened fitting to a laundry tap

Tags: plumbing, tape

I had a Plumber install this Y splitter on 3/4 BSP laundry tap. I now need to remove this split but am not able to rotate the fitting because of the pink coloured fastener in there. Can someone tell me how to remove the Y splitter ?

[image]

Comment: Does the splitter not have enough room to rotate with that PVC pipe there?

Comment: The splitter has room to rotate, I just find it quite hard to move .. I am afraid I may break the pipe connecting the tap , so not using sufficient force perhaps. Let me rephrase the question as to whether the pink stuff is just plumbing tape ?

Comment: Some info is missing here.  Why do you need to rotate the fitting?  Why di you have a Y put in in the first place?  Why can't  you just cap the open end of the Y? If a plumber did the job and it did not serve your needs, call him back to make it right.

Comment: The "pink colored fitting" looks like it might be epoxy or similar (ugh),  in whick case capping the unused leg of the Y may be much easier... Or remove and replace the whole valve.

Answer (score 1):

It was just Teflon tape and I managed to remove the splitter with a little force . Thanks you all for helping